# ModelMetadata.Container property is null

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, modelmetadata, modelmetadataprovider

I am writing a custom `ModelMetadataProvider` which extends default `DataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider`. Unfortunately i came across an issue:
**`ModelMetadata.Container` property is always null**. According to msdn description of `ModelMetadata Class`, container property should not be null when model represents a property:

[image]

But when overriding `GetMetadataForProperty` method, after calling base implementation Container property always returns as null:

[image]

```
protected override ModelMetadata GetMetadataForProperty(
            Func<object> modelAccessor, 
            Type containerType, 
            PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor)
        {
            ModelMetadata metadata = base.GetMetadataForProperty(modelAccessor, containerType, propertyDescriptor); 

            // metadata.Container always null here                
        }
```

On the other way, when accessing `ModelMetadata` from `ViewData`, `Container` property gets filled as expected:

[image]

Thus I have couple of questions related to this issue:

1. Is it an expected behavior that ModelMetadata.Container returns empty from `GetMetadataForProperty` or it is a bug?
2. Is there a way to get `ModelMetadata.Container` property filled inside ModelMetadataProvider?
3. When ModelMetadata.Container property actually gets it's content?

Answer (score 3):

Metadata is created from the innermost properties out, so the container model's metadata has not yet been created at the time `GetMetadataForProperty` is called (the same applies for `OnMetadataCreated` when you implement `IMetadatAware`). The reason you can acess it from `ViewData` is that the process of creating all metadata has been completed.

Comment: First of all thank you for the answer but I noticed a following behavior that slightly contradicts with it: each time that I hit Html.EditorFor in the view i see that it calls for GetMetadataForProperty. ViewData.ModelMetadta.Container is available prior to this call so how come it is not available in inside GetMetadataForProperty that is called after?

Comment: Interesting. Some time ago I was trying to work out the same problem your having and created a model containing a value type and a complex object, which in turn contained a value type and a complex objects (3 levels deep) and debugged it, which showed that the metadata was being created from the inner properties out. Time for some more tests :)

Comment: @StephenMuecke any resolution on this?  Having reference to the container type would be quite helpful

Comment: @AaronHudon, I remember doing a few tests on this at the time, but it was a year ago and I cannot remember now what the outcome was. I'll try and find some time next week to follow it up again.